# Dynamicly change values in form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've mistake with following script. I'd like to change value in profit inpunt, when i change value in total. But this not worked correctly. The value in profit input is changed, when I click again in input.

**HTML:**

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td> <input class="price" name="price" value="50"/> </td>
            <td>
                <input class="profit" name="profit" value="10"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="profit_type" class="profit_type">
                    <option value="$">$</option>
                    <option value="%">%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="total" name="total" value="60"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> <input class="price" name="price" value="50"/> </td>
            <td>
                <input class="profit" name="profit" value="20"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="profit_type" class="profit_type">
                    <option value="$">$</option>
                    <option value="%">%</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="total" name="total" value="70"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
                $('table tr').on('click', function(e) {
            var that = $(e.target);
            var tableRow = $(this);

                if (that.is('.total')) {
                    var price = parseFloat(tableRow.find('.price').val());
                    var total = parseFloat(tableRow.find('.total').val());
                    var profit_type = parseFloat(tableRow.find('.profit_type').val());
                    var profit = parseFloat(tableRow.find('.profit').val());

                    console.log(total);

                    if(profit_type == '%'){
                        profit = ((total - price)/price)*100;
                    }else{
                        profit = total - price;
                    }
                        tableRow.find('.profit').val(profit);
                }

            });
```

**EXAMPLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dilyan_kn/uTqMk/

Comment: You may like to update your question with the requirement for the behaviour to also happen when you change the profit type, instead of just calling people out on not reading your mind ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just target a `change` event on the total input, not a click on the entire row. Very little else has to change (assuming the other logic is correct) just the first 2 lines:

```
$('.total').on('change',function(){
    var $total= $(this);
    var $tableRow = $total.parents('tr');

    var price = parseFloat($tableRow.find('.price').val());
    var total = parseFloat($total.val());
    var profit_type = parseFloat($tableRow.find('.profit_type').val());
    var profit = parseFloat($tableRow.find('.profit').val());

    console.log(total);

    if(profit_type == '%'){
            profit = ((total - price)/price)*100;
    }else{
            profit = total - price;
    }
    $tableRow.find('.profit').val(profit);

});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/uTqMk/2/

---

As commented, you wanted to do the same when the `profit_type` select box is also changed, in which case you could refactor to behave the same for both:

```
$('.total, .profit_type').on('change',function(){
    var $tableRow = $(this).parents('tr');

    var price = parseFloat($tableRow.find('.price').val());
    var total = parseFloat($tableRow.find('.total').val());
    var profit_type = $tableRow.find('.profit_type').val();
    var profit = parseFloat($tableRow.find('.profit').val());

    console.log(total);

    if(profit_type == '%'){
            profit = ((total - price)/price)*100;
    }else{
            profit = total - price;
    }
    $tableRow.find('.profit').val(profit);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/uTqMk/4/

Comment: @Neel - fancy elaborating a little? What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: yes... it is, if you change the value in the total box as the OP requested.

Comment: If you change the profit type the value in profit input don't change.

Comment: Ok, but you never asked for that ("I'd like to change value in profit inpunt, when i change value in total.")... its easy enough to fix give me a mo

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
$('table tr').on('change', function(e) {

                var tableRow = $(this);


                        var price = parseFloat(tableRow.find('.price').val());
                        var total = parseFloat(tableRow.find('.total').val());
                        var profit_type = (tableRow.find('.profit_type').val());
                        var profit = parseFloat(tableRow.find('.profit').val());
                       console.log(profit_type);
                        console.log(total);
                        console.log(profit_type);
                        if(profit_type == '%'){
                            profit = ((total - price)/price)*100;
                        }else{
                            profit = total - price;
                        }
                            tableRow.find('.profit').val(profit);


                });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uTqMk/3/)

[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uTqMk/6/)

Comment: It doesn't work. The same problem. If you change the profit type the value profit not changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, a select box does not raise a `keyup` event when you click it.

Comment: @dido if this solution is working as per your comment mark or vote as you want

Answer (score 0):

why can't you try with change event.Here the problem was you are using click event on a table row , again when you click on the table row , the changes are getting affected.
So , change it to "change" event or try directly like taking input from the text boxes , calculating the result and displaying that in the profit  text box.